# Fatal Exception: IndexOutOfBoundsException using Picasso (only happen in some device)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, picasso

Recently I notice this fatal crash happens to my android app.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Index: 1, Size: 0

The issue happens when user click into item page, and fail to load index 1 from my banner array and setting the image to drawable.

I tested the app with a few different brand android devices, but they all works fine without crashing. Most Importantly I was able to load the image from array and set the image.

The log is as below:

1. ava.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException
   (ArrayList.java:255)
2. java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:308)
3. **com.midasmind.app.mmgocarmm.DetailActivity.onCreate (DetailActivity.java:222)**
4. android.app.Activity.performCreate
   (Activity.java:6303)
5. com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
   (ZygoteInit.java:629)

But then, it is so weird that only about 5% of my users are having this problem. (approximately 100-200 active users daily). One of my friend got this crash once when he loads into the item page. But he only crashed once, and he is a regular users that been using the app for couple session daily.

Here are the codes that I have for my item page:

(DetailActivity.java:222 = Picasso.with(this).load(sidebannerAry.get(sidebanner1index).get("image")).into(sidebanner1Btn); )

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity{
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> sidebannerAry = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    int sidebanner1index = 1;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sidebanner1Btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sidebanner1btn);

    sidebanner1Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent b = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sidebannerAry.get(sidebanner1index).get("url")));
            startActivity(b);

        }
    });
    Picasso.with(this).load(sidebannerAry.get(sidebanner1index).get("image")).into(sidebanner1Btn);
}
```

And this is the code I use to retrieve data from database during app start up screen:

```
                JSONArray sidebannerAry = result.getJSONArray("sidebannerData");
                for (int i = 0; i < sidebannerAry.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject temp = sidebannerAry.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    String image = DefensiveClass.optString(temp, "bannerImage");
                    String url = DefensiveClass.optString(temp, "bannerURL");

                    map.put("image", image);
                    map.put("url", url);

                    DetailActivity.sidebannerAry.add(map);
                }
```

Can anyone help me take a look and see if I did anything wrong?
Thank you so much.

Comment: For whatever reason, you're not putting at least 2 elements into `DetailActivity.sidebannerAry` (because the `sidebannerData` JSON array doesn't have at least 2 elements). You'd need to work out why that is.

Comment: Why sidebannerAry is static?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused, can you explain a little more?

Comment: It seems strange to keep images url in static field in one of activites. It could be error prone. I'd suggest to create new class like SidebannerCache and make it singleton (using DI). This class will be responsible for image caching and url retrival.

Comment: Can you  show me example on this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens in the following line :-

> (DetailActivity.java:222 =
>   Picasso.with(this).load(sidebannerAry.get(sidebanner1index).get("image")).into(sidebanner1Btn);
>   )

In the above line, the only part where an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` can occur is this :-

`sidebannerAry.get(sidebanner1index)`

You've set the value of `sidebanner1index` as "1". So, you're getting an error in the cases when the `sidebannerAry` has less than 2 elements. That is why only a certain percentage of your users is getting this error.

Index out of bounds error happens when you try to access an index that is higher than the length of the data structure.

The easiest way to solve it is to put a flag before the Picasso line that checks wether the `sidebannerAry` has a length that is higher than the `sidebannerIndex`.

Comment: I have 6 banners data stored in data base. And, 0, 2 and 4 are for iOS use, and 1,3 5 are fore Android use.

Comment: Perhaps the `sidebannerAry`'s data isn't populated by the time the Picasso line is called. Or, maybe the asynchronous nature of Picasso calls lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Regardless, these are only the probable causes of the problem. The problem is that during the time of this call, the `sidebannerAry` has 0 elements, and you're trying to access the index 1.

Comment: Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 1, Size: 0

This line also states the size to be 0, and the index being accessed to be 1.

Comment: I think it is most likely that at the time of Picasso call the sidebannerAry has 0 elements. But that is so weird, because the data was collected immediately after the app is launched, and secondly if the call and data collect order is incorrect, I should be seeing more crashes from all the users, and it only affects 5% of the users and my testing devices are working fine.

Comment: Temporarily, I set that when sidebanneryary is larger than 0 will run the above code, otherwise, the picasso will load up image directly from url.

Comment: Yes, that is a great temporary solution. Hope you find a solution that better aligns with the rest of your code.